# Variables in the first Maxwell equation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

The first Maxwell equation:

$$\vec\nabla \vec E(\vec r)=\frac {\rho(\vec r)}{\epsilon_0} .$$

But why both variables in the electric field and in the charge density are of the same letter, in this case $\vec r$. If we are in some volume/space and we have a charge distribution, there is a vector $\vec r'$ that points from the origin of our coordinate system to the charge distribution/cloud and there should also be another variable $\vec r$ that points to an arbitrary point in space, which is the point in which we want to find the value of the electric field generated by the charge distribution. That means that the above Maxwell eq. should look like this:

$$\vec\nabla \vec E(\vec r)=\frac {\rho(\vec {r'})}{\epsilon_0} .$$

Why isn't it like this though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

... ''*which is the point in which we want to find the value of the electric field generated by the charge distribution*''...   But then you must have a function $\:f[\rho(\mathbf r'),\mathbf r]\:$ that provides the information of how the charge density $\:\rho(\mathbf r')\:$ at point $\:\mathbf r'\:$ contributes to the divergence  $\:\boldsymbol{\nabla\cdot}\mathbf E(\mathbf r)\:$ at point $\:\mathbf r\:$ and consequently sum or integrate over $\mathbf r'$. Then you would have an integrodifferential  equation. So your second equation as written has no sense. The contribution is local. May be you are confused of how the electric charge density $\:\rho(\mathbf r')\:$ and the electric charge current density $\:\mathbf j(\mathbf r')\:$ at point $\:\mathbf r'\:$ contribute to the values of the scalar and vector potentials $\:\phi(\mathbf r)\:$ and $\:\mathbf A(\mathbf r)\:$ at point $\:\mathbf r\:$
in classical electrodynamics.

Comment: That is probably what I don't get. We usually measure values for the electric field/ electric potential at some point away from the cluster of charges, but at the same time I can understand why also looking at a location within the distribution its possible

Answer (score 3):

The equation relate the divergence of the electric field in the point $\vec{r}$ with the charge density in the same point $\vec{r}$.
Maybe you are getting confuse with the Coulomb law applied to a charge distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The two prior answer are correct, nevertheless: The equation does not relate the electric field at ${\bf r'}$ to the charge density at ${\bf r}$, rather it related the divergence of the electric field at the same point as $\rho$.

In order to find an electric field at ${\bf r}$, you need to integrate over all other $\rho({\bf r'})$ and use the divergence operator's Green's Function (aka: Propagator) to propagate those effects to ${\bf r}$:

$$ {\bf E}({\bf r})=\frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0}\iiint_V
\frac{\rho({\bf r'})dV}{({\bf r'}-{\bf r})^2}\hat{\bf r}'$$

Substitution of that ${\bf E}$ into Maxwell's equation (that is: taking the divergence) will yield $\rho({\bf r})/\epsilon_0$.